# Copy raw rasters referenced by a Mosaic Dataset in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.1

Tags: raster, arcgis-pro, mosaic

Is there a tool in ArcGIS Pro 2.2.1 that allows me to select and copy the raw underlying rasters referenced by a Mosaic Dataset to a folder?

Comment: Do you mean Mosaic Dataset, Raster Catalog or Raster Dataset? they are 3 slightly different things.. but no, there is no out-of-the-box tool to copy the underlying raster in any of these 3 raster types (there is Copy Raster but I don't think that's what you want). What is it you're trying to achieve here? There may be a satisfactory way to solve this simply if we understand why and what end you're hoping to get to.

Comment: Sorry I meant Mosaic Dataset - (now corrected).  My Mosaic Dataset references underlying 'raw' rasters (tif images).   When a customer wants a copy of the underlying tifs for a particular area of our othroimagery, I would like to be able to select an area of the Mosaic Dataset in ArcGIS Pro and then export the underlying raw tifs to a folder.  I did write a python tool a few years ago for ArcMap that essentially did just this, but I was wondering if ArcGIS Pro already had this functionality built in?

Comment: Correct about Copy Raster - I think it only allows for Mosaic processed imagery to be copied out or something like that.

Comment: I'd be interested to see such a tool, it's not easy to get the full paths of the *base* rasters from a catalog given a screen extent; was this in arcpy or ArcObjects? Copy Raster will export the entire mosaic dataset to a single raster dataset - unless you modify your environment extent to match the view, in which case you will get a single raster of what's on the screen.

Comment: Was in ArcPy - I'll put it up into github and post the link back here

Comment: I oversold that script (it's been a while) - wrote it for raster catalogs back in 2011.  Source code is here: https://github.com/localgovernment/CopySourceRasters  @MichaelStimson can you please submit your answer (no out-of-the-box solution) so that I can select as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no out-of-the-box solution to export a selection of rasters from a mosaic dataset.

You can use [Copy Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000094000000) with your [environment extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001w00000009000000) set to `Same as Display` to export a single raster with the extent of the current view.

It's not easy to get to the rasters in a mosaic dataset, you can open a search cursor on one:

```
with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(r'D:\Testing\KCat.gdb\KCat2','Name') as sCur:
     for row in sCur:
         print row[0]
```

But this will give you the overview tiles as well; only the raster names are stored; only the name of the raster can be accessed, not the full path, you would have to know that in advance to copy the base rasters.

Note: even calling the 'Raster' field returning [raster objects](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000) you cannot access the `catalogPath` or `path`; I have even tried describing the `row[0]` raster object, paths are nonsensical being `D:\Testing\KCat.gdb\AMD_KCat2_CAT\Raster.OBJECTID = 357` (the mosaic dataset is in `D:\Testing` and called `KCat2`).

You might possibly be able to get the information in ArcObjects, if you're that way inclined, the object is [IMosaicDataset](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/IMosaicDataset_Interface/001q00000m8s000000/)

If you already know where your mosaic dataset has its rasters stored you could use a simple script from ArcMap:

```
import os

FocusDataFrame      = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("Current"))[0]
arcpy.env.workspace = r'c:\path\to\your\rasters'
OutFolder           = r'c:\where\you\want\to\save\to'
DataFrameExtent     = FocusDataFrame.extent

for R in arcpy.ListRasters():
    Ras = arcpy.Raster(R)

    if Ras.extent.overlaps(XTnt):
        arcpy.AddMessage('Saving {}'.format(R))
        Ras.save(os.path.join(OutFolder,R))
    else:
        arcpy.AddMessage('Skipping {}'.format(R))
```

This gets the [extent](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000072000000) of the dataframe then iterates the rasters in the nominated folder, checking for overlap with the dataframe extent and if there is an overlap uses the save method of the [Raster object](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//018z00000051000000) to copy the tile. From here, and based on your posted code, I can see that it would be very easy for you to modify this simple process to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question and I'm not sure if this was available with Pro 2.2.1 but there is a GP tool for this - [`arcpy.management.ExportMosaicDatasetPaths`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm). It will produce a table containing full file paths of each raster. [`arcpy.conversion.TableToTable`](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/conversion/table-to-table.htm) can be used to convert the table to CSV. `ExportMosaicDatasetPaths` can also be combined with [extent](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/analysis/geoprocessing/basics/extent-control.htm) to only export a subset of file paths matching the extent.